# Are <Application_Home>/Documents synced automatically to iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

For iCloud-enabled devices, is an app's "Documents" directory stored automatically in iCloud without any work required from the developer?

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html): *"Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the /Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud."*

However, it's unclear if we get this functionality "for free", or if dev needs to take any measures (incorporate Cloud Kit etc.).